# How to group and count the number of rows that start with the same 3 characters?

Tags: mysql

Example column/input:

```
abcddd
abdfff
abdeee
abcrrr
```

Output:

Would tell me that 2 rows start with `abc` and 2 start with `abd`.

How could I build a statement like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT LEFT(`field_name` , 3) AS first_chars, COUNT(*) 
FROM `your_table` 
GROUP BY LEFT(`field_name` , 3)
```

Above query will give you this output ,

abcddd

abdfff

abdeee

abcrrr

defghi

field_name | count

abc  | 2

abd | 2

def | 1

Comment: I'm unable to test it because of the size of the database but this seems about right. Thanks!